# Default iterator implementation for array of Object (T[])?

Tags: java, arrays, iterator, java-8

I have a class looking something like the code below. It implements the `Iterable<T>` iterface, which it uses to provide iteration capabilities over its contained array.

I have been in the habit of rolling my own trivial iterator to iterate over arrays. I just realized, however, that at least for *spliterators*, you can get an acceptable default implementation by calling [`Arrays.spliterator(array)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#spliterator-T:A-). Is there a similar default implementation of an ordinary `Iterator<T>` over an array of `T`?

```
public class MyClass implements Iterable<ContainedClass>
{
    ...
    private final ContainedClass[] array;
    ...

    //
    // INTERFACE: Iterable<ContainedClass>
    //

    @Override
    public Iterator<ContainedClass> iterator() {
        return ??? // I want to return a default implementation, not my own!
    }

    @Override
    public Spliterator<ContainedClass> spliterator() {
        return Arrays.spliterator(array);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Closest thing to a default implementation in the JDK:

```
Arrays.asList(array).iterator()
```

Simple custom implementation:

```
public final class ArrayIterator<E> implements Iterator<E> {
    private final E[] _elements;
    private int _index;

    @SafeVarargs
    public ArrayIterator(final E... elements) {
        _elements = Objects.requireNonNull(elements);
    }

    public boolean hasNext() {
        return _index < _elements.length;
    }

    public E next() {
        if (hasNext()) {
            return _elements[_index++];
        }
        throw new NoSuchElementException();
    }

    public void remove() {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As already [pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25433709/2711488), you can simply use `Arrays.asList(array).iterator()` to create an array iterator. The temporary list is a lightweight wrapper and is nothing to worry about.

Alternatively you can use `Arrays.stream(array).iterator();` which is equivalent. The advantage of using `Arrays.stream(array)` instead of `Arrays.asList(array)` is that there is the overload `Arrays.stream(T[] array, int startInclusive, int endExclusive)` similar to `Arrays.spliterator` so there is no big change if you ever need to process a range of the array.